# Why does this regex (see inside) match 24+? (and how to matches the exact pattern)

Tags: regex

This is the regex:

> [0-9]|([0-1][0-9])|2[0-3]

Aim: match numbers: 0 to 23

(working version:

> ([0-1][0-9]?)|2[0-3]

)

The issue with the **first** version ([0-9]|([0-1][0-9])|2[0-3]):

To me this means: match these numbers (or a string/number containing them)

- 0,....,9
- 01, ...., 09
- 10, ..., 19
- 20, ..., 23

but it matches also **24** for example. Why?

I also tried (to match the **exact** pattern and not a potential superset):

- to use **\b** at beginning and end of pattern. Result: **matches 0 until 10 only**
- to use ^ (beginning) + $ (end) but 20, 21, ... are **not matched**

**Tried in http://regexr.com/**

Comment: It doesn't.  Are you sure you haven't got global matching turned on, and you're seeing two different matches, for `2` and `4`, [for example](https://regex101.com/r/vA4wR5/1).

Comment: you're right. but removing global flag for example doesn't match 23

Comment: That's a different issue - it's finding the `2` first within the first alternation, then stopping.  I think you need to think a bit more about what you want to ask with this question - there's a few things going on here.

Comment: `^([0-9]|([0-1][0-9])|2[0-3])$` or this `\b([0-9]|([0-1][0-9])|2[0-3])\b` works. Note the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't use anchors. Try

```
^([0-9]|([0-1][0-9])|2[0-3])$
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oU0jO9/1).

It could be simplified somewhat though:

```
^(1?\d|2[0-3])$
```

It tests the whole string - `^` matches the beginning and `$` the end. Then it has two alternatives inside a group (surrounded by `()`) - first an **optional** `1` followed by any digit (handles 0-19). The other alternative matches a `2` followed by 0-3 (handles 20-23).

It's slightly simpler, **but** it doesn't allow for leading zeroes, so if you need that it'll have to be

```
^([01]?\d|2[0-3])$`
```

Comment: Or `^([0-9]|(?:[0-1][0-9])|2[0-3])$` for only one capturing group, so you don't get things twice sometimes.

Comment: @Marco thanks to your contribution. However it's not clear how it'd work

Comment: @ClasG yes, it seems working! why does the anchors make the difference?

Comment: Very simple, `?:` makes the middle group a "non-capturing" group. But it works exactly the same ...

Comment: thanks Marco. @Clas, can you explain the simplified version in detail please?

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to select it as the "accepted answer", otherwise clarify what else you're wondering about.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misinterprete what [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) displays as a match.

Considering your example text `24`:

1. Either you have the *global flag* `g` activated which yields *two* matches (this flag tells the regex engine to continue matching and return all other matching numbers in the text)
2. Or, your are overlooking that your pattern still matches *parts* of the text, because `2` is a match even if it is followed by a `4`.

So if you want your program to reject strings that represent a number beyond the range [0, 23] you have to extend your pattern such that it won't accept anymore digits after the specified ones.

You could, for instance, use the *anchors* `^` and `$` that match the start and end of the string respectively:

```
^([0-9]|([0-1][0-9])|2[0-3])$
```

Comment: thanks for the very clear answer. can you please clarify what "overlook" means?

Comment: Consider `24` as input. Your regex pattern will match this text, because its first alternative (`[0-9]|`) matches the `2` in it. That might be not what you expected.